# What is => this[var] in type script

Tags: typescript

I migrate from angular 4.2 ("typescript": "~2.3.3") to 12 ( "typescript": "~4.3.2") and just don't know what type of syntax is it.

The thing is in => **this[layerVar]**

Angular 12 with more modern types script gives this error, if I set type of the argument => layerVar as any

[image]
If I don't say any type
[image]

```
drawOnMap(feature, radius, isArray, layerVar = null, style = null) {
    layerVar = layerVar || 'myLayer'
    style = style || this.myStyle

    if (!isArray && feature.geometry.type.includes("Multi")) {
      feature.properties = { gid: 123 };
      let features = [feature];
      this[layerVar] = new L.geoJson(features, {
        style: style,
      })
        .addTo(this.map);
    } else if (!isArray && feature.geometry.type == "Point" && radius) {
      this[layerVar] = new L.geoJson(feature, {
        pointToLayer: (feature2, latlng) => {
          return new L.Circle(latlng, radius);
        },
      })
        .addTo(this.map);
    } else if (
      (!isArray && feature.geometry.type == "Point")
      || (feature[0] && feature[0].type == "Point")
    ) {
      this[layerVar] = new L.geoJson(feature, {
        pointToLayer: (feature2, latlng) => {
          return new L.Marker(latlng, { draggable: false });
        },
      })
        .addTo(this.map);
    } else {
      this[layerVar] = new L.geoJson(feature, {
        style: style,
      })
        .addTo(this.map);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`=> this[layerVar]` is not legal syntax on its own. It only makes sense as part of an arrow anonymous function literal, something like this:

```typescript
layerVar => this[layerVar]
```

Unfortunately, it is not 100% clear from your question, which *exact* part of the syntax you are struggling with, so I will explain all of them:

```typescript
foo => bar
```

This is an [*arrow anonymous function literal*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#anonymous-functions). Unfortunately, the TypeScript documentation on this is pretty terrible, *specifically* when it comes to syntax, which is what you are talking about. [Here is the specification of the syntax in ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ArrowFunction), which is where TypeScript gets its inspiration from, but this obviously does not include syntax for type annotations:

> - *ArrowFunction*<sub>[In, Yield, Await]</sub> :
>     *ArrowParameters*<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub> [no *LineTerminator* here] **`=>`** *ConciseBody*<sub>[?In]</sub>
> - *ArrowParameters*<sub>[Yield, Await]</sub> :
>     *BindingIdentifier*<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub>
>     *CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList*<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub>
> - *ConciseBody*<sub>[In]</sub> :
>     [lookahead ≠ **`{`**] *ExpressionBody*<sub>[?In, ~Await]</sub>
>   **`{`** *FunctionBody*<sub>[~Yield, ~Await]</sub> **`}`**
> - *ExpressionBody*<sub>[In, Await]</sub> :
>     *AssignmentExpression*<sub>[?In, ~Yield, ?Await]</sub>

```typescript
this
```

This is the *`this` keyword*. Again, I couldn't find any documentation about the `this` keyword in TypeScript (in fact, I couldn't find any comprehensive syntax documentation of TypeScript at all), so [here is the definition in ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-this-keyword):

> - *PrimaryExpression*<sub>[Yield, Await]</sub> :
>     **`this`**

(Not very exciting, I know. Hey, it is a keyword, what did you expect.)

```typescript
foo[bar]
```

This is an *indexed property access*. There is also no documentation about this in TypeScript, unfortunately. (There is practically no documentation at all about the runtime semantics, the statement syntax, or the expression syntax of TypeScript, since they are identical to ECMAScript, and it is assumed that TypeScript programmers know ECMAScript. There is only documentation about the type syntax and type semantics.)

The [syntax documentation for ECMAScript is here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-MemberExpression):

> - *MemberExpression*<sub>[Yield, Await]</sub> :
>     *MemberExpression*<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub> **`[`** Expression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await]</sub> **`]`**

```typescript
layerVar
```

This is simply an [*identifier reference*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-IdentifierReference).

Those are the four syntactical elements that make up the fragment you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `layervar='mylayer'` as a parameter in your function.
That means if this value of layervar is null when the function is called it will default to 'mylayer'.
The Type will be String too. As Typescript guessed the type by the default value.

```
drawOnMap(feature, radius, isArray, layerVar = 'mylayer', style = null) { ...
```

And remove this line:

```
layerVar = layerVar || 'myLayer'
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah it seems to me as a solution, but there is still an error for the line this[layerVar] = new L.geoJson(feature, { ... I just never seen construction (syntax) like that. Well anyway, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: If you share the error I might be able to help.

Comment: The same as was => Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'AmapComponent'